# Testing service workers with IIS local server

Tags: asp.net, caching, testing, iis, service-worker

I'm testing offline functioning of service workers on a local website on IIS

This is what I'm doing for manual test running:

```
1. No IIS caching
2. Removed all ISS cached files(\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files)
3. Stop IIS each test run
4. Unregister service workers each test run in browser
5. Delete all cached files in browser
```

When I'm manual test running, the service worker sometimes still stay registered or some pages still stay cached. And other irregularities arise.

What am I forgetting to successful manual test run?